# Large RSS feed requests to non-existent URL causing 404 (and high load)

Tags: nginx, wordpress, cloudflare

Recently I had a new site launced completly replacing a previous site.

We have cloudflare in front and switched the host-name to the new site IP.

Instantly we saw load go above 200+ and a constant stream of HTTP replies of 404 of around 25Mbps (i guess wasnt higher as CPU cores were at max).

From what I could see there were many hits per second to rss.xml (which no longer existed on the new site whereas it did on the old).

This request in turn was going in to WordPress initiating the WP load sequence, which loaded some plugins (with suspect non-performant code) and the sheer number of requests per second cause very high server load.

To prevent this in future:

1. Can one rate limit via nginx the requests to this RSS URL (or any other URL)?
2. Is there any way to prevent WordPress from taking the server down and exit quickly if a file is not found, as opposed to loading non-cached pages (and all subsequent plugins) just so it can render a 404 page?

Comment: Is there a reason you do not cache the 404 output?  Cloudflare would then answer all except the off question here and there. And the rss.xml should actually redirect to the new location ;)

Comment: @TomTom Because WordPress is stupid and sends no-cache headers on 404 pages.

Comment: Oh my. so you really have a bad setup. Get THAT fixed.